# Manually set page number in latex

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am writing my PhD thesis. My table of content is fine except for the first entry. I am getting out put like following

```
 Table of contents
  Inner page  ii
  content    ii
```

I want to change the first entry to page number i, like following:

```
  Table of contents
   inner page  i
    content ii
```

I have tried several ways but non is working. Following working example.

```
     \documentclass[12pt]{report}
      \usepackage{tcolorbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox
      \usepackage{caption}
      \usepackage{setspace} % for \onehalfspacing
     \usepackage{titlesec}
     \usepackage{etoolbox} % package is used for formattig table of content

     \begin{document}
     \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
       \include{cover_page} 
        \pagenumbering{roman}
       \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty} 
       \include{copyrightpage}
       \addtocontents{toc}{~\textbf{CHAPTER NO.}\hfill\textbf{TITLE}\hfill\textbf{PAGE NO.}\par}
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inner first page}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

        \tableofcontents

       \end{document}
```

**cover_page.tex**

```
\begin{onehalfspace}
 \begin{center}
 \textbf{\LARGE{}title}{\LARGE{}}\\
  \vspace{1cm}

  \par\end{center}
   \end{onehalfspace}

   \begin{center}
    \textit{\large{}Thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements
     for the Degree of}
       \par\end{center}{\large \par}

    \vspace{1cm}


     \begin{center}
     \textbf{\Large{}DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY}
    \par\end{center}{\Large \par}

      \vspace{1cm}


     \begin{center}
      by
       \par\end{center}

    \vspace{1cm}


        \begin{center}
    \textbf{\large{}Name\\ Enrollment No. (101)}
    \par\end{center}{\large \par}

    \vspace{1cm}


       \begin{center}

      \begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}%
      \begin{center}


        \end{center}%
     \end{minipage}

        \end{center}

      \vspace{1cm}


      \begin{center}
      {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}Dept}
    \par\end{center}

     \vspace{0.25cm}


        \begin{center}
       {\fontsize{12pt}{12pt} UNIVERSITY name
         \\  }
       \par\end{center}

     \vspace{0.5cm}
```

**Copyrightpag.tex**

```
 ~~\\ 
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
     {\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}@ Copyright }
       \end{center}
```

I have attached the output that I am getting.

Please let me know how I can do that. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: This isn't a minimal working example because we don't have the files cover_page or copyrightpage; also, most of the code isn't related to the problem and should be omitted. With the code you provided, I can't reproduce the result you're getting.

Comment: If you use book [oneside] instead of report you can use the \frontmatter, \mainmatter, \backmatter divisions.

Comment: Thanks magula and john. I have provided the coverpage and copyrightpage as asked by you. Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MWE the `\addcontentsline` commands both are excecuted on the same page. This page is the first page of table of contents because `\include` uses a `\clearpage` after inserting the file. So you have to change the order of your code a bit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{~\textbf{CHAPTER NO.}\hfill\textbf{TITLE}\hfill\textbf{PAGE NO.}\par}%
}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{cover_page} 

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inner first page}
\include{copyrightpage}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]